# Installing elementaryOS

Tags: virtualbox, elementary-os

**Can anyone tell me what is necessary to get elementaryOS installed in a virtualbox on a Windows7 host?**

I came across [elementaryOS](http://elementaryos.org/) a few days back and I have been trying to install it in a VirtualBox.

However, each time I have downloadeded it and attempted to select the elementary iso in storage settings of my virtualbox, my downloaded elementary iso CD file is not visible and hence not selectable.

The file download in named in the following format:
elementaryos-stable-amd64.20130810

Comment: Virtual Box may look for certain file endings. Have you tried appending `.iso` to your downloaded image filename?

Comment: Yes, I did that but it still wasn't recognised

Comment: It's super-stupid, but removing the dot from "amd64.20130810" helps? Other than that you have created a CD-ROM device in Virtualbox and you try to select it from there, right? (http://askubuntu.com/questions/64915/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-virtualbox-client-from-an-iso-image).

Answer (score 0):

Change the host os to `Other OS`. I believe it may be looking for `*ubuntu*.iso` or something stupid like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed elementaryOS 5.1.5 with Ubuntu Settings and it works.

[image: VirtualBox Settings]